# CMake check_function_exists only called one time in macro

Tags: cmake, macros

I have a CMake macro that calls check_function_exists() to detect several math functions.

By the output below, it seems that check_function_exists() is only called the first time;

```
macro(nco_check_funcs func def)
message(${ARGV0})
check_function_exists(${ARGV0} have_result)
message(${have_result})
if (NOT have_result)
  message("-- Using NCO defined version of ${ARGV0}")
  add_definitions(-D${ARGV1})
endif()
endmacro(nco_check_funcs)

nco_check_funcs(atan2 NEED_ATAN2)
nco_check_funcs(acosf NEED_ACOSF)
nco_check_funcs(asinf NEED_ASINF)
```

in the example below the macro is called 3 times, but the output of
check_function_exists() only shows up 1 time

```
atan2
-- Looking for atan2
-- Looking for atan2 - found
1
acosf
1
asinf
1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those results of [`check_function_exists()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckFunctionExists.html) are cached.

> Check that the `<function>` is provided by libraries on the system and store the result in a `<variable>`. `<variable>` will be created **as an internal cache variable**.

Add the following to the begin of your macro:

```
unset(have_result CACHE)
```

Or if you want to keep the functionality of only searching once for the function (and cache the result), you need the variable name to depend on the function like this:

```
check_function_exists(${ARGV0} have_result_${ARGV0})
```

Now each search for a function has its own result variable.

**Reference**

- [`unset()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/unset.html)