# cmake check_type_size issue when using the same variable in multiple calls

Tags: cmake

I am trying to write a basic cmake to check whether certain types exist or not. 
I am having issues with calling check_type_size multiple times. If I used the same variable (the one that holds the size) multiple times, only the first time I call check_type_size it gets populated.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(TEST LANGUAGES C;CXX)
INCLUDE (CheckTypeSize)

check_type_size("int" VAR_SIZE1)
message(${VAR_SIZE1})
check_type_size("void *" VAR_SIZE1)
message(${VAR_SIZE1})
message("VAR_SIZE1 was not updated after the second call.\n")


check_type_size("int" VAR_SIZE2)
message(${VAR_SIZE2})
check_type_size("void *" VAR_SIZE3)
message(${VAR_SIZE3})
message("We get the correct size if use different variable every time.")

add_executable(TEST "${TEST_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp")
```

This is what I get:
    Check size of int
    Check size of int - done
    4
    4
    VAR_SIZE1 was not updated after the second call.

```
Check size of int
Check size of int - done
4
Check size of void *
Check size of void * - done
8
We get the correct size if use different variable every time.
```

Does any body know what is going on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake check\_function\_exists only called one time in macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46204710/cmake-check-function-exists-only-called-one-time-in-macro). Just put your type checks in your own wrapper macro that handles the variable naming.

Answer (score 2):

Variable created with `check_type_size()` call is actually a **CACHE** variable (this is described in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/module/CheckTypeSize.html) for the macro. Once variable is set, its is not updated. [This is used for omit successful checks next time you run `cmake`.]

**Different checks** should use **different variables.**

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that it's a cache variable. Is it possible to avoid using a new variable every time I call that macro. 
I am only interested in making sure that certain types exists.

Comment: You may use [unset(CACHE)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/unset.html) command after the `check_type_size()` call for clear the variable from the cache. I have seen such usage in some projects, so may be it has a sense. But I find using different variable each time as more cleaner way.